# How do I install Ubuntu Studio 13.04 from a DVD?

Tags: system-installation, dvd, ubuntu-studio

I burned the 32-bit ISO image to a blank DVD.  So next, I put the DVD (with all its contents) into the drive and when I open it, there are a bunch of different folders. If I try to open any file in a folder, it says:

```
Could not display "/media/Ubuntu-Studio 13.04 i386/install/mt86plus"."
```

and

```
the file is of an unknown type.
```

What do I do?  Is there a specific software I need JUST to install it?  Sort of like a catalyst?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to boot your PC with the bootable DVD you created.

As for installation procedure, you may find the following link very helpful http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Also; if you need to install as a Dual boot system. Please you have to **BE VERY CAREFULL** and do not proceed with any step or make any selection oryou may break your current operating system or even worse; destroy all data on your hard drive.

And by the way **It is not very complicated in this OS as you said** . You just need to be familiar with and know what you are doing :) and you will then Fall in love with it ;)

A last note : I would highly recommend using **Try Ubuntu without installing** to get familiar with before actually installing it (Not sure if available in the Ubuntu Studio specifically as I never used it) but you may download Ubuntu ISO from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmadgeo! This would be very helpful, if I was trying to download Ubuntu (the OS), but I'm actually just looking to install Ubuntu Studio. It's an audio editing, mixing, etc software for Ubuntu. Similar to Garage Band for Mac, but better. I'm actually using an Ubuntu OS right now.

Comment: Wait. I think I misunderstood. Ubuntu STUDIO is a whole separate operating system?

Comment: @Newb by definition in **About** section under <www.ubuntustudio.org> Ubuntu Studio is : Ubuntu Studio is a free and open source operative system, and an official flavor of Ubuntu. Ubuntu Studio is the most widely used multimedia orientated GNU/Linux distribution in the world. It comes preinstalled with a selection of the most common free multimedia applications available, and is configured for best performance for the Ubuntu Studio defined workflows: Audio, Graphics, Video, Photography and Publishing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for upgrading your current Ubuntu installation to Ubuntu Studio:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video
```

Check [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu). After all, all the difference between a Ubuntu flavor and another is the pre-installed software :)